# Subtract a number from the rows until the number ends to zero

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-update, window-functions

How can subtract a number from the rows to the end of the subtraction in MySQL with query update

If have table like this

```
Store Table
itemId  storeCode   qoh
1          1        20
1          2        30
1          3        40
```

and i want subtract "**80**" form qoh to get the output

```
itemId  storeCode   qoh
1          1        0
1          2        0
1          3        10
```

I tried by and not work

```
set @sum = 80;
Update store SET qoh =
(SELECT IF((@sum := @sum - qoh) > 0,0,qoh))
ORDER BY storeCode ASC;
```

What is the appropriate adjustment to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do the computation with window functions.

The following `select` query gives you the expected results:

```
select
    s.*,
    case when sum(qoh) over(partition by itemid order by storecode) - qoh >= 80 
        then qoh
        else greatest(
            sum(qoh) over(partition by itemid order by storecode) - 80,
            0
        )
    end new_qoh
from store s
```

You can then turn this to an `update`:

```
update store s
inner join (
    select 
        s.*, 
        sum(qoh) over(partition by itemid order by storecode) sum_qoh
    from store s
) n 
    on  n.itemid = s.itemid 
    and n.storecode = s.storecode
    and n.sum_qoh - s.qoh < 80
set s.qoh = greatest(n.sum_qoh - 80, 0)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e428205c851032c66acbb68174351d82)**:

```
itemId | storeCode | qoh
-----: | --------: | --:
     1 |         1 |   0
     1 |         2 |   0
     1 |         3 |  10
     1 |         4 |  50
```

I added an extra line at the end of your data to demonstrate that the queries leave the "following" `qon` untouched.